# Why serverless endpoint urls in not working?

Tags: node.js, api, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have followed this https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-express-rest-api/
to setting up serverless framework on AWS. I am successfully getting end points on cmd. But when I am hitting the end point url on browser, Json response is coming like {"message": "Internal server error"}

Please check my code below, and let me know where am I wrong.
//index.js

```
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

//sererless.yml

```
service: my-express-application
provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs6.10
    stage: dev
    region: us-east-1
functions:
    app:
        handler: index.handler
        events:
            - http: ANY /
            - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to cloudwatch to see more specific logs

Answer (score 0):

> when I am hitting the end point url on browser, Json response is coming like {"message": "Internal server error"}

This suggests that the functions is setup correctly, but when AWS spins up your code and executes it, an error is thrown.

You options to debug and get to the bottom of this include (in order of decreasing efficiency/ROI, IMHO):

- Looking at the cloudwatch logs
- wrapping as much code as possible in a try/catch block, to return a more meaningful error via HTTP
- [blindly] remove parts of your code, making is simpler each
  time, until it runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this issue, just change the events variable in serverless.yml (honestly, I dont know why event: http ANY / doesnt work but the following works well)

```
    events:
  - http:
      path: /{any+}
      method: ANY
```

Check this [url](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-http/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md)